# Flutter: Unable to convert http response to podo object

Tags: flutter, dart

XKCD.dart

```
class XKCD {
  final String id;
  final String imageURL;
  final String safeTitle;

  XKCD({this.id, this.imageURL, this.safeTitle});

  factory XKCD.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return XKCD(
    id: json['num'],
    imageURL:json['img'],
    safeTitle:json['safe_title'],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:fluttermvpillustrativeapp/data/xkcd_data.dart';

class ProdXKCDRepo {
  String baseURL = "http://xkcd.com/";

  Future<XKCD> fetchComicPost() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(baseURL + "info.0.json");
    final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    final statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print (XKCD.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); // No value gets printed
      return XKCD.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }

  }
}
```

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<XKCD> comicPost;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    comicPost = ProdXKCDRepo().fetchComicPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("XKCD comic"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.file_download),
            tooltip: 'Download',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.share),
            tooltip: 'Share',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _comicBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _comicBody() {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<XKCD>(
        future: comicPost,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: PhotoView(
                      imageProvider: NetworkImage(snapshot.data.imageURL),
                    ),
                  ),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind), onPressed: null),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left), onPressed: null),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong), onPressed: null),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right), onPressed: null),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fast_forward), onPressed: null),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          }
          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I use it in the `FutureBuilder` getting error `imageURL is null` and the spinner is loading infinitely.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<XKCD>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<XKCD>#b4c12):
The getter 'imageURL' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: imageURL
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: did you. check statusCode by printing it?

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact when I try to print the `response.body` I am getting all the details. But can't convert to podo.

Comment: your id is of type string are you sure you are getting it as string? can you add response.body response.status?

Comment: response body - {month: 5, num: 2301, link: , year: 2020, news: , safe_title: Turtle Sandwich Standard Model, transcript: , alt: It's possible the bread and shell can be split into a top and bottom flavor, and some models additionally suggest Strange Bread and Charm Shells., img: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/turtle_sandwich_standard_model.png, title: Turtle Sandwich Standard Model, day: 1}

status code - 200

Comment: And I have changed the data type from String to int.

Comment: you forgot to add return keyword in following place. if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[

Comment: Dang. Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add return keyword in following place.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) { return Column( children: <Widget>[
```

and because of that you are not getting updated UI.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to avoid this error before the image loads? 
``` ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<XKCD>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<XKCD>#462b2): The getter 'imageURL' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: imageURL ```

Comment: it should not give you that error. can you try flutter clean and run again?

Comment: you are printing print(snapshot.data.imageURL); before if condition. just remove  print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your error can be fixed by adding a `return` statement right before your column in the future builder.

See code below:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.network('${snapshot.data.imageURL}'),
                ),
                flex: 1,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fast_forward), onPressed: null),
                ],
              )
            ],
          );
        }
```

Output: 
[image]

Hope it helps.

FULL CODE:

```
Widget _comicBody() {
  return Center(
    child: FutureBuilder<XKCD>(
      future: ProdXKCDRepo().fetchComicPost(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.network('${snapshot.data.imageURL}'),
                ),
                flex: 1,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right), onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fast_forward), onPressed: null),
                ],
              )
            ],
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
          );
        }
        // By default, show a loading spinner.
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea before the image loads I am getting this errors ?

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<XKCD>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<XKCD>#462b2):
The getter 'imageURL' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: imageURL

```

Comment: Check my answer again, I updated it with the full code of _cosmicBody() @Madhan

Comment: @Madhan, I hope that helps you. You can vote the answer if it does.

Comment: At first error message is displayed, then progress bar loaded and after the image is displayed. Instead of error message being displayed is it possible to show progress indicator ?.

Comment: Remove the else if statement and the error text wont show. @Madhan

Comment: I tried it. Not working.
```
Syncing files to device Moto G 4...
I/flutter (14506): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14506): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<XKCD>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (14506): _FutureBuilderState<XKCD>#3b3d1):
I/flutter (14506): The getter 'imageURL' was called on null.
I/flutter (14506): Receiver: null
I/flutter (14506): Tried calling: imageURL
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213001/discussion-between-random-guru-and-madhan).